# Changes highlight in asp.net (like beyond compare) : Text or HTML comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need to highlight changes(diff) between 2 database text fields in a asp.net application.

I'm used to "beyond compare" text compare, so the Ideal solution will do something like it, but if it just highlight the differences, that would be OK.

http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextCompare

The content is HTML, so if it could compare the HTML rendered text, it would be even better.

So, i need a link or a control (free if possible) to do that job.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking is pretty complex. I can't find any control out there that will do this, but i did find this: [Difference Algorithm for C#](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/Default.aspx)

It doesn't give you exactly what you need, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: In fact, it's more that I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this question and it looks like there are more recent options - eg. [Html Diff algorithm for .NET](https://github.com/Rohland/htmldiff.net)